# Increasing or decreasing theta based on direction of vector

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, circles, tangent-line

I am a programmer, and I have some holes in my math knowledge that I am working on filling in. Right now I'm working with a simple process involving drawing curves and straight lines. The line that is drawn has direction and magnitude, and at a random time, there is a circle drawn perpendicular to the straight line, and the line begins to arc around this. I have the arc working. I find theta using atan2, and then I *increase or decrease* it at a steady rate. Then after a random period of time, the arc stops, and the line continues off along the tangent line.

Increasing or decreasing theta is my issue right now. Instead of smoothly drawing along the circle, it will abruptly begin drawing the arc with theta increasing. I just don't know how to figure out the rule behind increasing or decreasing theta based on the vector. I have a feeling that this will also help me understand how to make it smoothly "leave" the curve, instead of jerk backwards and draw the wrong direction along the tangent line. Below is a simple illustration of how I want it to draw. This is with theta decreasing, with theta set to increase, the red would draw below the dotted line.

[image]

Working on building my math vocabulary, but it's not quite there, working on it. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you show more examples? Show an example where it "jerked backwards" and explain what you did there, and show an example with theta increasing. What tools are you using?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the poor photo, it would take me way too long to tame my javascript to actually illustrate this nicely.

Comment: So a ray is directed towards a circle and will meet the circle tangent to the circle, and when it hits the circle, you want it to trace the circle in one or the other direction?

Comment: Correct. In the smoothest way possible (drawn in red).

Comment: Well, your description (constant increase/decrease of angle, using atan to find a direction) seems correct, so it's hard to tell what your problem is. You want to increase/decrease theta at a rate that is constant with respect to the length of curve you draw, so it should work to trace out successive line segments of the same length $\ell$ (small), each one in a direction $\theta$ (small angle) clockwise/counterclockwise from the previous one. One reason it's hard to help you is that you don't show what goes wrong and you don't say what kinds of basic drawing operations are available to you.

Comment: The problem is just how to predict whether or not clockwise or counterclockwise movement will be necessary. Really the only hunch I have is that it can be figured out by direction of the vector and whether or not the circle to be traced is on the left or the right of the point. I'll look further into that today, maybe it comes down to a boolean when the circle is generated to the left or the right of the line.